# Cannot use PHP var in a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show each row where **userCZ = $_SESSION['user']**, but whenever I try with the var, it doesn't find nothing at all. 
If I replace the var for a literal string, It works perfectly.
I've also tried to check if the var is not empty and it returns the proper value at the begin of the script.
I think I am missing something in the syntax but I've tried with '' and "" and still not working.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $userCZ=$_SESSION['user'];


require_once __DIR__ . "/../../init.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/../../functions/db.php";

if (isset($_GET['start']) && isset($_GET['end'])) {
$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM the_events WHERE userCZ = '$userCZ' AND start_date >= 
:start and end_date <= :end';
$_events = QuickPdo::fetchAll($stmt, [
    'start' => $_GET['start'],
    'end' => $_GET['end'],
]);



$events = [];
foreach ($_events as $e) {
    $events[] = [
        'id' => $e['id'],
        'title' => $e['title'],
        'project' => $e['project'],
        'start' => dateMysqlTime2Iso8601($e['start_date']),
        'end' => dateMysqlTime2Iso8601($e['end_date']),
    ];
}
echo json_encode($events);
}
```

Comment: one thing is that you have `'SELECT * FROM the_events WHERE userCZ = '$userCZ' AND start_date >= 
:start and end_date <= :end'`, but you need a `.` to separate the different parts of the strings

Comment: You should enable error logs, this should be causing an error. You also should bind `$usercz`.

Comment: echo your $stmt variable and see what it is outputs. Variable values are not substituted in single quotes (') so use $stmt = "SELECT * ....."

Comment: Change all those values to placeholder values. You're doing it for `:start` and `:end`, so do it for the rest. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to do this.

Comment: Based on the mistake made here you need to use a syntax highlighting text editor that can instantly show you any mis-steps in formatting your code. This is pretty obvious using even Stack Overflow's own internal formatter.

Answer (score 2):

This can be addressed by binding all of the dynamic values:

```
$_events = QuickPdo::fetchAll(,
  'SELECT * FROM the_events WHERE userCZ = :userCZ AND start_date >= :start and end_date <= :end',
  [
    'userCZ' => $userCZ,
    'start' => $_GET['start'],
    'end' => $_GET['end'],
  ]
);
```

Avoid using string interpolation unless you have no other option, and when that occurs, take every possible precaution to ensure you're doing it safely.